# Configure Python's Flask-User Setting Using Gunicorn and Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask-login

I need to override the default Flask-User setting [USER_ENABLE_LOGIN_WITHOUT_CONFIRM](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/api.html) which is false and make it true. I declare in my app the following

```
app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
app.config['USER_ENABLE_LOGIN_WITHOUT_CONFIRM'] = True
```

in my procfile I have the following

```
web: gunicorn main:app --log-file=-
```

This however still prompts a user to have a confirmed email when trying to login. How can I override the default setting for flask and get the user to log in without having a confirmed email?

Comment: I haven't user `Flask-user`, but it looks to me like you should also change `USER_ENABLE_CONFIRM_EMAIL = False`.

Comment: @dasdachs Close, it is actually USER_ENABLE_LOGIN_WITHOUT_CONFIRM_EMAIL = True though. The documentation is wrong on the page. I found that by scouring through their github repository issues.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply